# Execute YAML templates from Azure DevOps classic pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I would put my questions through following points, hope it's make clear now:

1. The application source code is in application_code repo.
2. The pipeline code(YAMLs) are in pipeline_code repo. Because I'd like to version it and don't like to keep in application_code repo. Just to avoid giving control to Dev team to manage it.

Problem statement:

- The pipeline YAML won't be triggered unless it's in the source code repository based on the events pr, commit etc.
- Can we trigger or execute YAML file which is in pipeline_repo whenever there's event triggered in application_code repo?

I've tried achieving above using Classic pipeline and YAML template but this don't work together. As I can execute a YAML template from a YAML pipeline only not from a classic pipeline like below:

```
#azure-pipeline.yaml
jobs:  
  - job: NewJob
  - template: job-template-bd1.yaml
```

Any ideas or better solution than above?

Comment: define: "execute a template yaml file"?

Comment: Why use the classic at all when you already have a yaml file defined? I don't see any reason not to use a yaml pipeline importing or extending the template as a PR build validation and CI pipeline.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? It's not clear why you want to do this.

Comment: You can use yaml pipeline to execute a template yaml. Classic pipeline cannot do this.

Comment: I have edited my original question so that it can make sense. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @JoshGust Because I don't wanna keep this yaml in main source control repository rather want to keep in some other repository which is dedicated for DevOps.

Comment: `Just to avoid giving control to Dev team to manage it.` This sounds like you're not using permissions and branch policies appropriately. Why not let developers change the yaml pipeline if they need to and put a devops engineer as a required reviewer for that path on the master branch policy?

Comment: Not to mention, if you're abstracting away the "guts" of the pipeline into template `.yml` files, I don't see why you wouldn't allow the "shell" pipeline to live in the app repo and the template to live in the templates repo. Again, using permissions to restrict dev access to the templates as necessary. The shell pipeline can be nothing more than a place holder and parameters definition (composition root) for the templates.

Answer (score 0):

The feature **Multi-repository support for YAML pipelines** will be available soon for azure devops service. This feature will support for triggering pipelines based on changes made in one of multiple repositories. Please check [Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline) or [here](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1454026). This feature is expected to be rolled out in 2020 Q1 for azure devops service.

Currently you can follow below workaround to achieve above using **Build Completion**(the pipeline will be triggered on the completion of another build).

> 1, Setup the triggering pipeline

Create an empty classic pipeline for application_code repo as the triggering pipeline, which will always succeed and do nothing.

And check **Enable continuous integration** under **Triggers** tab and setup **Bracnh filters**
[image]

> 2, setup the triggered pipeline

In the pipeline_code repo using `Checkout` to [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path). You can specifically checkout the source code of  application_code repo to build. Please refer below example:

```
steps: 
  - checkout: git://MyProject/application_code_repo@refs/heads/master # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization

  - task: TaskName
     ...
```

Then in the yaml pipeline **edit page**, click the **3dots** on the top right corner and click **Triggers**. Then click **+Add** beside **Build Completion** and select above triggering pipeline created in step 1 as the **triggering build**.

[image]

After finishing above two steps, when changes made to application_code repo, the triggering pipeline will be executed and completed with success. Then the triggered pipeline will be triggered to run the real build job.

Update:

> Show Azure DevOps Build Pipeline Status in Bitbucket.

you can add a python script task at the end of the yaml pipeline to update the Bitbucket build status. You need to set a `condtion: always()` to always run this task even if other tasks are failed.

You can get the [build status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions) with env variable `Agent.JobStatus`.  For below example:

For more information, please refer to document [Integrate your build system with Bitbucket Cloud](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/integrate-your-build-system-with-bitbucket-cloud-790790968.html), and also [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Show-Azure-DevOps-Build-Pipeline-Status-in-Bitbucket/qaq-p/1186099).

```
  - task: PythonScript@0
      condition: always()
      inputs: 
        scriptSource: inline
        script: |
          import os
          import requests

          # Use environment variables that your CI server provides to the key, name,
          # and url parameters, as well as commit hash. (The values below are used by
          # Jenkins.)
          data = {
              'key': os.getenv('BUILD_ID'),
              'state': os.getenv('Agent.JobStatus'),  
              'name': os.getenv('JOB_NAME'),
              'url': os.getenv('BUILD_URL'),
              'description': 'The build passed.'
          }

          # Construct the URL with the API endpoint where the commit status should be
          # posted (provide the appropriate owner and slug for your repo).
          api_url = ('https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/'
                    '%(owner)s/%(repo_slug)s/commit/%(revision)s/statuses/build'
                    % {'owner': 'emmap1',
                        'repo_slug': 'MyRepo',
                        'revision': os.getenv('GIT_COMMIT')})

          # Post the status to Bitbucket. (Include valid credentials here for basic auth.
          # You could also use team name and API key.)
          requests.post(api_url, auth=('auth_user', 'auth_password'), json=data)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. In above scenario, won't I be able to capture the status of the last triggered build job? Because the build job will give me the real status of build completion and the same needs to be updated on Bitbucket page.
However in this case the Bitbucket will always show success as the first trigger pipeline always send success.

Comment: @rajeevsharma i think you can try reconfiguring your Bitbucket to show the real status of the build job. You can also refer to my update to update the build status to Bitbucket via Bitbucket Api.